# Adding new classes to inception

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

How to add more classes to tensorflow's inception so that it can recognise predefined 1000 classes + the new class which I add? Is the any way of doing this

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrain the last layer of your inception model with old and new data. See the [tensorflow image retraining](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining) tutorial for more information.

Comment: Thank you but how will I get the old data ?

Comment: You can download imagenet or something.